# Rails drop down list error undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, drop-down-menu

I have 3 models: customer, employee, ticket. 
I want to use a drop down list to select employee_id when I create a new ticket but it's giving me this error

```
undefined local variable or method `employee' for #<#<Class:0x3f2c880>:0x3f4a070>

Extracted source (around line #16):

13: 
14:     <div class="field">
15:       <%= f.label :employee_id %><br />
16:       <%= f.select :employee_id, employee.all.map{|s| [s.name, s.id]} %>
17:     </div>
18:     <div class="field">
19:       <%= f.label :customer_id %><br />
```

As far as I understood, this has to be because I didn't set employee as a global variable . I saw this line in the controller though:

```
def new
    @employee = Employee.new
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What exactly you want to fetch there in the employee_id select box? in that dropdown lists all the **Employee** ids in your database?

Comment: Sagar, I'm trying to list employee_id from the employee model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using `employee.all` which assumes that you want to access a local variable called `employee`.  changing that to `Employee.all` would solve your issue.

Comment: I changed `employee.all` to `Employee.all` and it gave me ``undefined method `name' for #<Employee:0x3e972b8>``

Comment: that means you have no `name` column for employee.

Answer (score 1):

Declare an instance variable in your controller action as follows:

```
def new
    @employee = Employee.new
    @employees = Employee.all
end
```

Now in your view, use this instance variable

```
<%= f.select :employee_id, @employees.map{|s| [s.name, s.id]} %>
```

This is <strike>probably</strike> better than accessing your model directly from view like `Employee.all`

Comment: @jvnill I got ``undefined method `all' for #<Array:0x3e52b40>``